# Javascript: Pause program flow until button clicked

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon chaps..

I'm trying to create a function in Javascript that generates an on screen dialog similar to the msgbox function in VB/VBA.  I've so far managed to code the msgbox function in Javascript so that when it is called it dynamically creates a dialog on screen.

It works like this:-

```
if (msgbox("Do you want to continue", YesNo) == Yes) {
      //Do something here
}
```

What I would like to know is this - is there any way I can halt/pause the flow in code until one of the buttons in my dynamically generated dialog is pressed?  I don't want the 'Do Something here' bit or any other following code to run until a user has clicked the 'Yes' button in my dialog.

(NOTE:  YesNo and Yes, in the example above are constants.   The dialog works perfectly up to this point I just need to figure how to stop flow until a button is pressed without overcomplicating things).

Mat

Comment: Is your message box an html element, or a modal dialogue like what would be created by a call to `alert` or `confirm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the confirm box this should work for you - it fires a prompt with ok/cancel options:

```
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue?")){
//executed when OK clicked
}
else{
//executed when CANCEL clicked
}
```

Note workflow is paused in the function until an answer is given

Comment: I know about CONFIRM, but I want more flexibility for the user and something less 'Windows-y' as a dialog.

Comment: Have you tried using a jquery plugin e.g. http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/ ?

Comment: @MatRichardson It sounds like you're looking for some sort of a lightbox, then.

Comment: I could do, but I want to figure this out myself so I can learn more about the technology.  Whilst using ready-made code is something I do often, in this case I want to bake it myself..

Comment: I've personally never tried to create one myself, I'm big fan of jQuery and the various plugins it offer especially http://jqueryui.com/ which also has a dialog plugin. There are some helper pages on creating your own [plugins](http://web.enavu.com/js/jquery/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin/)] if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a little late but I would do the following (assuming only two possible choices, i.e., yes or no and also assuming a modal type confirm box is being used and not the garden variety alert/confirm boxes):

Add this variable storage form to your html (note value for the form's hidden input is not listed and is therefore currently a null value)

```
<form id="UserSelection" style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="yes_or_no">    
</form>
```

Then add two buttons to your modal confirm box in which button "yes" triggers a "yes" value and button "no" triggers a "no" value for the hidden input of the form:

```
<div id="ModalConfirm">
<button type="button" onclick="StoredSelectionVar('yes')">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="StoredSelectionVar('no')">No</button>
</div>
```

where the function StoredSelectionVar() is defined as:

```
StoredSelectionVar(type) {
    if (type === 'yes') {
        document.forms['UserSelection']['yes_or_no'].value = 'yes';
    } else {
        document.forms['UserSelection']['yes_or_no'].value = 'no';
    }
}
```

and then modify your remaining javascript as follows:

```
function YesOrNo() {
var x = document.forms['UserSelection']['yes_or_no'].value;
if (!x) {
    window.setTimeout(YesOrNo, 1000);<!--Modify time as desired.....checks form 
    UserSelection to see if a value is present, which implies the user clicked either    
    the yes or no button for the hidden input, or no click if still a null value, in 
    which case the function is called again and the process repeated-->
} else {
    if (x === 'yes') {
        //Do This
    } else {
        //Do that
    }    
}

function yourFunction() {
    if (msgbox("Do you want to continue")) {
        YesOrNo();
    } else {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `alert()` and `prompt()` in JS for this sort of thing. Alert is for simple messages that only need acknowledgement, prompt can return some input.

Comment: I know this, but I want the user to be able to specify which buttons appear in the dialog like in VB/VBA (eg Yes, No, OK, Cancel etc).  Alert and Prompt don't offer this functionality.

Comment: No such beast in JS, then. You could build a modal dialog that overlays some DOM stuff on the page.

Comment: This is what I've done..  what I need is to know how to pause program flow in my code until a button has been pressed.

Comment: no such beast in js, except tight loops and the alert/prompt functions. You could work around it by splitting your code in two parts, and having the second part called only after a button in your pseudo-dialog gets clicked.

Comment: That was what I was trying to avoid really but guessed that I wouldn't be able to pull it off in the way I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an HTML element, you want to set the `onclick` property of the yes button to be a function that contains the desired action, or you can use `addEventListener` for modern browsers.

```
function doStuff () {
    // do stuff here
}

button.onclick = doStuff;
```

The way you should structure your scripts is that there is some top-level code that is necessary to set up global variables or top level functions, and do anything else that you want to happen as the page loads.  Then you create functions to do callbacks on various user actions (clicking/hovering/keystrokes, etc).  There's no real "pausing" going on, but you can defer functions so that they only execute in response to user input.

If you want to block other user actions while you do this the way a modal dialog does, you'd have to set state via a global variable or property of some object, and have all your callbacks check that before executing. This could easily get complicated, and might be a reason to prefer using a simple `confirm` prompt.

Comment: I don't really want to do that as I would ideally like the function to do the lions share of the work.  Any code following the function should essentially be 'on hold' until a button has been clicked.

Comment: Because I want the function to be re-usable by users.  If you're aware of the msgbox function in VB/VBA you'll get what I mean.  It pops up a dialog and waits for a response from the user before continuing.  I want to build a simple function (as I have) that does the same thing without overcomplicating things for the user.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't do VB/VBA, so I don't know what you're thinking of, but I've elaborated on how you design scripts around callbacks. It's actually a lot cleaner and less complicated than any idea of pausing the script, imho.

Comment: I know it is, but this was the specific functionality that I was after.  I basically want the user to be able to use this function in their code in place of the PROMPT (for example) so that they can respond to questions like "Are you sure?" - YES/NO without needing additional functions or callbacks, just a simple function that returns either yes or no and then continues based on the return value of the function.